# Transfer files between two Ubuntu machines over ftp

Tags: mount, ftp, cifs, smb, protocols

I wonder how I can transfer files between two machines running ubuntu using FTP? Also what is the best fastest configurations to transfer files over ubuntu (cifs, smb, ftp,...)? Also is it worth it to modify the kernel to as shown here https://darksideclouds.wordpress.com/2016/10/10/tuning-10gb-nics-highway-to-hell/  ?

Comment: `sftp` is usually readily available and offers a secure alternative to `ftp`. Do you have specific reasons for using the latter? About the "best" way: it is generally found by benchmarking, it depends on you systems and on your exact use case (this also applies to kernel tweaks).

Comment: @fra-san So can you tell me how to do transfer between to Linux workstations using sftp?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at existing posts, e.g. https://askubuntu.com/q/420652/882661. Most of the work is [setting up the OpenSSH server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring). Then, as a basic an not-so-convenient way, you can connect using `sftp server` and transfer files in a ftp-like fashion (`get`, `put`, ...). Or use [sshfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS) to mount a remote directory locally. Or connect by the means likely provided by your graphical file manager.

Comment: @fra-san But I read that ssh is not as fast as sftp, right?

Comment: SFTP is FTP over SSH, so that doesn't sound likely. If you mean SSH compared to FTP, then sure, SSH introuces some overhead because the connection is encrypted. But I don't think you'll experience a significant difference in throughput, and in general people want their connection to be secure (encrypted) anyway.

Comment: @fra-san so the best way would be connect to the other machine with ssh then doing a rsync?

Comment: As I said, IMO there is no "best" way. Also, Stack Exchange's Q/A format isn't really good for this kind of discussion. My only suggestion would be to edit your question to make it focus on a specific issue and answerable in a not-too-subjective way. (I'll also delete my comments here, I don't think they would be useful to others).

Comment: My two cents worth of information: I instatl `openssh-server` in one of the computers and use `sftp` a lot (for single files or a few files), and `rsync`, particularly when I want to copy or backup a whole set of files (typically a directory tree) . Try them and stay with what works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you've looked at rsync? That may server you better than ftp.

Rsync  is  a  fast  and  extraordinarily versatile file copying tool.  It can copy locally, to/from another host over any remote
shell, or to/from a remote rsync daemon.